# Cheap multi-route (open-jaw) flights

Tags: air-travel, budget, open-jaw

I need to get a flight Prague(PRG) -> Paris(CDG) and Paris(CDG) -> Budapest(BUD), in June. The Air France web system offers me an unbelievable price EUR 680.

If I try similar thing on the Czech Airlines system with a flight PRG->CDG and Geneve(GVA)->PRG, the price is cca EUR 160, similar to a return ticket PRG->CDG.

It seems that Czech Airlines are willing to consider such a ticket as "return" and offer the cheapest tariffs. However, Czech Airlines obviously won't offer me the flight I need.

Is there a way to convince Air France (or someone else) to offer me such a ticket? I know I can use the low-costs, but they are the last option for me, almost equivalent to taking the circa-20-hour trains.

*(I apology if any of the "cheap flights" questions treat precisely the "different return" tickets, I wasn't able to find such information.)*

Comment: This kind of flight setup is called an open-jaw. You can search about that term to get more information.

Comment: see also http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/10133/46

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try a multi-search engine. For example, I've tried to find a multi-stop flight PRG -> CDG -> BUD in June with [LastMinute](https://www.lastminute.ie/site/travel/flights/multi-stop.html?DPMUL=1) and this is the result:

[image]

If you don't want to go in a low-cost, you can flight with Lufthansa + Swiss Airlines for less than 200 euros. Air France, as other companies, don't consider multi-stop flights (in Europe, Air France in USA accepts internal multi-stop flights).

Comment: This looks promising, I'll check it in details, thanks!

Comment: @tohecz: good luck and don't forget to mark as valid the answer if it is ok

Comment: having 20k+ SE rep, I know how the system works ;) In the end, I'll do a bit different trip PRG->CDR, GVA->PRG->BUD, BUD->PRG and buy everything from Czech Airlines (for the cheapest fares). However, that website you show is very good!

Answer (score 2):

I know you said you don't like low cost airlines, but **Skypicker.com** is a European (Czech) low cost air tickets search engine where you can find some of the lowest fares. It may well prove very helpful for the route you wish to take:

http://www.skypicker.com/levne-lety-z-velka-britanie

For 8th June 2013, Prague to Venice, Venice to Budapest the price would be 119.40 Euros (excluding taxes & fees of 18 Euros)

[image]

The trade off of course would be the time taken to reach Budapest >8 hrs.

Other tickets had varying prices, however the duration of travel is far longer, if you made your stopover in Paris (as you mentioned) the duration of travel is doubled & the price is approx. 170 Euros:

[image]

However the saving compared with paying 680 Euros that you quoted in your question I think makes up greatly for the time taken to travel, if you were to choose Venice as your stopover (in my honest opinion).